# Confirm Hyper-V Integration Services are Running

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, hyper-v

I am trying to confirm that Hyper-V Integration Services Daemons are running.

I have tried to install all daemons so I'm looking to verify the following:

```
VSS Snapshot daemon

KVP daemon

fcopy daemon

"HWE kernel" # Virtual Kernel
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v

Comment: KVM is the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out as I'm back to using Hyper-V for work.

```
root@openproject:~# systemctl status hv-fcopy-daemon.service
● hv-fcopy-daemon.service - Hyper-V File Copy Protocol Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hv-fcopy-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-14 17:27:44 UTC; 6min ago
 Main PID: 1249 (hv_fcopy_daemon)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2224)
   CGroup: /system.slice/hv-fcopy-daemon.service
           └─1249 /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.0.0-1031-azure/hv_fcopy_daemon -n

Feb 14 17:27:44 openproject systemd[1]: Started Hyper-V File Copy Protocol Daemon.
Feb 14 17:27:44 openproject HV_FCOPY[1249]: starting; pid is:1249
Feb 14 17:27:44 openproject HV_FCOPY[1249]: kernel module version: 1
root@openproject:~# ps -u root | grep fcopy
  1249 ?        00:00:00 hv_fcopy_daemon
root@openproject:~# ps -u root | grep hv
    31 ?        00:00:00 hv_vmbus_con
    32 ?        00:00:00 hv_pri_chan
    33 ?        00:00:00 hv_sub_chan
   511 ?        00:00:00 hv_balloon
   526 ?        00:00:00 hv_kvp_daemon
  1249 ?        00:00:00 hv_fcopy_daemon
  1260 ?        00:00:00 hv_vss_daemon
```

Note: on older systems you may need to use `ps -u root | grep hyper`

Note: These are all the process in a list that I found

```
hv_vmbus_con
hv_pri_chan
hv_sub_chan
hv_balloon
hv_kvp_daemon
hv_vss_daemon
hv_fcopy_daemon
```